# Maass-Hecke construction

Tags: langlands-conjectures, automorphic-forms

I heard this name that it can construct GL(2) automorphic forms or L-functions from GL(1)?
I did not find it anywhere. 
Or does it have another name which we are familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automorphic Induction. Look at Bumps book on Automorphic reps in the first chapter.

Comment: Also Blomer-Brumley discuss this here: The role of the Ramanujan conjecture in analytic number theory, Bulletin AMS 50 (2013), 267-320

Comment: This question is so vague that the answer he's looking for might be "Eisenstein series" instead! 